# jquery draggable / droppable change snap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am attempting to create a series of drag/droppable divs.
Once div1 has been dropped, i will create a new div and have it snap at a new position.
However the snap position remains the same when div1 has been dropped and div2 is being dragged:
( http://jsfiddle.net/kLpgukkj/2/ )

```
var trackID = "path0";
var trackType = "a";

$('.map-track-box').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        // RETURNS HOME
        $('#trackDragger').animate({ top: '30px', left: '20px' },500);
    }
});

$('#'+trackID).droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        // IN POSITION
        var pos = $('#'+trackID).position();
        $('#trackDragger').animate({ top: pos.top, left: pos.left },500,function() { 
            $('#draggerBox').append("<div class='"+trackType+"' style='z-index:10;position:absolute;top:"+pos.top+"px;left:"+pos.left+"px;'></div>");
            $('#trackDragger').css({ top: '30px', left: '20px' },500);
            $('#trackDragger').attr('class', 'd');
            $('#'+trackID).removeClass('ui-droppable'); // I attempted to remove the added class, and add it to the new element, but without luck
            if(trackID=="path0") {
                trackID = "path1";
            }else if(trackID=="path1") {
                trackID = "path2";
                trackType = "d";
            }else if(trackID=="path2") {
                trackID = "path3";
                trackType = "e";
            }
            $('#'+trackID).addClass('ui-droppable');
        });
    }
});


$('#trackDragger').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(event,ui) {
        $('#trackDragger').attr('class', trackType);
    },
    snap: "#"+trackID, // This keeps snapping to initial div (path0) even though trackID is being changed to path1,path2 etc
    snapMode: "inner",
    stop: function(){
        var dragPos = $('#trackDragger').position();
        if(dragPos.left < 101 && dragPos.top < 91) {
            $('#trackDragger').attr('class', 'd');
        }
        //$(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});
```

The above works well, but the dragged element keeps snapping to path0 (initial draggable div).
Is there anyway to force a new snap location ?

Thank you

Comment: can you make a fiddle for your problem so we can have a better idea on your problem!

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpgukkj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding:

```
$('#trackDragger').draggable("option", "snap", "#"+trackID);
```

will force it to snap to the new element.
Furthermore using

```
$('#'+trackID).droppable()...
```

would fail, as it apparently needs to be reinitialized in order to use a different element as droppable.

Answer (score 0):

As for the fiddle you've mentioned, you bind the `droppable` event only to one element. That is

```
$('#'+trackID) // Your variable don't change from "path0" to any other.
```

As I understand, you want the other black boxes also to have the droppable event bind.

Just change the code to the following in the `droppable` section.

```
$('.path').droppable({});
```

This would bind the event to every `.path` element in the page.

see the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLpgukkj/3/).

Comment: Hi Dimal.
The thing is, the snapping still only occurs at box1. It should snap to box1, then box2, then box3

Comment: If you look at lines 24-32, i change the trackID variable there.
I suspect some sort of re-initializing of the draggable might be needed ?

Comment: instead of re-initializing the plugin, if you could change line number 44 to `snap: '.path',` then it would snap to every element but would accept the next item which should accept the item! I've updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kLpgukkj/4/